# Perform multiple updates in a single query in an access database table

Tags: sql, ms-access-2016

In my access 2016 database, I have a table `tblCustomerInfo` with a field `customer_code`. There are some old `customer_code` values that need to be updated to newer values (for example, all rows with `customer_code = 103` should be updated to `customer_code = 122`).

I can achieve something like this going one `customer_code` at a time using queries like:

```
UPDATE tblCustomerInfo set customer_code = 122 Where customer_code = 103;
UPDATE tblCustomerInfo set customer_code = 433 Where customer_code = 106;
...
```

however, I would like to avoid having to run a separate query for each `customer_code`. Is there any way to update all the codes, each to a different new value, in a single query?

Comment: Please show sample data and expected output.  Your current question is not answerable.

Comment: My table is  tblCustomerInfo where the field I want to edit is customer_code. I have old codes like 101,103,106,etc...upto 25 several numbers which I need them to be updated 122,321,433 individually.   The update code which I wrote was -  UPDTAE tblCustomerInfo

Comment: My access table is  tblCustomerInfo where the field I want to edit is customer_code. I have old codes like 101,103,106,etc...upto 25 several numbers which I need them to be updated 122,321,433 individually.   The update code which I wrote was -                                           UPDTAE tblCustomerInfo    set customer_code  = 122 Where customer_code = 103;              but this is only good for an individual code. but I need to run a query which changes all the codes respectively to their new codes. thank you.

Comment: Rephrased question with additional information from the comments

Answer (score 1):

Create a table eg CustomerCodes with two fields oldcode and newcode, and add in all the values. Then run an update query like this:

```
UPDATE CustomerCodes INNER JOIN tblCustomerInfo 
ON CustomerCodes.OldCode = tblCustomerInfo.Customer_Code 
SET Customers.Customer_Code = [CustomerCodes].[NewCode];
```

Alternative

If there aren't too many to change you can use a switch statement like this:

```
UPDATE tblCustomerInfo 
 SET Customer_Code = 
SWITCH(Customer_Code=103,126,
Customer_Code = 106,130,
Customer_Code = 107,133);
```

There is, in my experience, a limit on the number of pairs you can have in a switch statement, although I have never bothered to find out exactly what the limit is - it doesn't seem to be documented.